# How to emit more events from a sink after an error

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to write some code to publish redis cache updates via a reactor sink.

I'm using the following sink:

```java
    private final Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);
```

And this is my omMessage listener:

```java
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        try {
            // Do some stuff
            sink.emitNext(new String(message.getBody()), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping(Duration.ofMillis(500)));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            sink.emitError(e, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping(Duration.ofMillis(500)));
        }
    }
```

And I return flux to multiple consumers using:

```java
    public Flux<String> getPublisher() {
        return Flux.from(sink.asFlux().publishOn(Schedulers.single()));
    }
```

When using the above code with a simple subscriber:

```java
redisPubSub.getPublisher()
.bufferTimeout(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, MAX_BUFFER_DURATION)
.mapNotNull(event -> {
// .... do stuff
})
```

Then as soon as my an error happens no other subscriber can subscribe to my sink. Even is I handle errors, the next time I try to subscribe it instantly just errors. What should I be doing about this? (Bearing in mind that I'm using a spring redis message listener which is multi-threaded).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's an expected behavior, any publisher stops on error. I guess you handle errors on the subscribers, but that has nothing with the sink. If you want to avoid breaking the sink you could try a diffrent way to notify about the internal failures, b/c `emitError` would certainly emit an error and therefore stop the sink.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Reactor reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling):

> In Reactive Streams, errors are terminal events. As soon as an error occurs, it stops the sequence and gets propagated down the chain of operators to the last step, the Subscriber you defined and its onError method.

What you can do depends on the location of the exception that caused your Flux to terminate. If the exception originated from the `// .... do stuff` block, you can handle it within the sub-chain instead of passing it to the main chain.

An example of code that replaces "failed event" with an empty mono and does not terminate the flux:

```java
var failureHandler = Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
Sinks.Many<Integer> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    sink.emitNext(i, failureHandler);
}

sink.asFlux()
    .flatMap(event ->
        Mono.just(event)
            .mapNotNull(e -> {
                if (e == 2) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
                }
                return e;
            })
            .onErrorResume(Exception.class, e -> Mono.empty())
    )
    .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("doOnNext: " + it))
    .subscribe();
```

It outputs:

```
doOnNext: 0
doOnNext: 1
doOnNext: 3
```

Please note that the number 2 is missing due to an exception that occurred while handling it.

Comment: This is kind of what I ended up implenting a while back. However, the problem with this (and my solution) is that you have to move the logic of determining whether to throw an exception etc is moved to every single consumer which wasn't ideal.